# custom fields and post types for Ghost

Tags: ghost

Does an equivalent of Wordpress “post types” and the Advanced Custom Fields plugin exist for Ghost?

As one example, I built a travel site that has multiple Trips (a custom post type), and each trip has various serialized itinerary destinations, tour guides, etc. Another example would be designer portfolios, where they might have a Projects post type, which contains serialized images, each with its own description and perhaps a date stamp or client or whatever.

Answer (score 4):

Not supported and probably never will be. Seems like this doesn't have high priority in their team.

See: https://forum.ghost.org/t/custom-fields-for-posts/1124/46 and https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/issues/9020